# iBeacon Receiver and Vuforia Autofocus not work on an Android tablet [Unity3d]

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ibeacon, vuforia

I have two problems, about autofocus on Vuforia's AR-camera and iBeacon receiver. These are not work.

However, I see these problem just on an Android tablet(me173x).
I tried with 3 Android phones and iPhone5, 5s and 6+. No problem on them.

Development Environments are:
MacBookPro-Retina15-Early2012 (FullSpec)
OSX 10.10.4 (Latest)
Unity 5.1.1p2 (Latest), Professional (but no iOS-Pro and no Android-Pro)
Vuforia 4.2.3 (Latest)

I captured screenshot of terminal running 'pidcat --min-level w' (levels above warning), because so many logs.

[image: snapshot of terminal]

No other logs above warning.

Error logs about linking of class for iBeacon found.
The tablet supports bluetooth 4.0 and BLE, and some camera apps support autofocus.

I guess... these problems due to the device architecture.

Please help me!

P.S.
thank you for your response, jacob.

my code to enable autofocus is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using System;

public class VuforiaARCameraAutoFocusMultiSelect : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializableAttribute]
    public struct FocusModes {
        public CameraDevice.FocusMode secondary;
        public CameraDevice.FocusMode primary;
    }

    public FocusModes iOSFocusModes;
    public FocusModes androidFocusModes;
    public FocusModes defaultFocusModes;

    void Start() {
        var qcar = FindObjectOfType<QCARAbstractBehaviour>();
        if (qcar != null) {
            qcar.RegisterQCARStartedCallback(OnQCARStarted);
            qcar.RegisterOnPauseCallback(OnQCARPaused);
            Debug.Log("QCARBehaviour Found in current scene");
        } else
            Debug.LogError("Failed to find QCARBehaviour in current scene..");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the QCAR started event.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnQCARStarted() {
        Debug.Log("OnQCARStarted");
        SetFocusMode();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the QCAR paused event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="paused">true: paused, false: resumed</param>
    private void OnQCARPaused(bool paused) {
        if (paused) {
            Debug.Log("OnQCARPaused");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("OnQCARResumed");
            SetFocusMode();
        }
    }

    private void SetFocusMode() {
        FocusModes modes;
        #if UNITY_IOS
        modes = iOSFocusModes;
        #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        modes = androidFocusModes;
        #else
        modes = defaultFocusModes;
        #endif

        if (CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(modes.primary))
            Debug.LogFormat("Successfully enabled autofocus mode: {0}", modes.primary);
        else if (CameraDevice.Instance.SetFocusMode(modes.secondary))
            Debug.LogFormat("Successfully enabled autofocus mode: {0}", modes.secondary);
        else
            Debug.LogError("Couldn't enabled autofocus!!");
    }
}
```

This code attached to the 'AR Camera' gameobject in the scene.

Comment: Please post the code you used for Camera Autofocus and iBeacon. Would help identify the problem easier.

Comment: thank you jacob! I added my code. On console log, success message printed. Actually, autofocus is unavailable...